# If statement works but else doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm creating a login form where I check the email and password if email and password are same user get login and redirect to index page .. but if user enter wrong email or password code doesn't go to else statement

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['login'])) // Login Validation check code ** START **

  $errr = ''; // This variable will be used to indicate error of login email or pwd

{
  include('connection.php');

  $loginemail= trim($_POST['loginemail']);
  $loginpass= trim($_POST['loginpass']);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE email=\"$loginemail\" and pass=\"$loginpass\"";

  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die(mysql_error());

  if(!empty($row))
  {
    $_SESSION=array();

    $_SESSION['fname']=$row['fname'];
    $_SESSION['lname']=$row['lname'];
    $_SESSION['status']=true;
    header('location: ../index.php');
  }
  else
  {
    echo " something wrong ";

  }
}  // Login Validation check code ** End **

?>
```

Comment: $row will never be empty. In many cases, empty() cannot be used with string variables for the simple fact that empty() returns true if your variable is set the the string value '0'. If the string character '0' is a possibly valid value for your string variable

Comment: check `if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)` instead empty

Comment: sidenote: dont dont dont use mysql_* functions,they are deprecated

Comment: Consider using mysqli or PDO. Curly braces {} opening should be after if condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting wrong here. you are wrongly started you first if condition

```
 if (isset($_POST['login'])) // Login Validation check code ** START **

    $errr = ''; // This variable will be used to indicate error of login email or pwd

    {
```

modify it

```
 if (isset($_POST['login'])) // Login Validation check code ** START **
 {
    $errr = ''; // This variable will be used to indicate error of login email or pwd]
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

for 2nd if you can use this

```
    // some changes in sql also you can use LIMIT 1 when you required exactly one result to be fetch. 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE email='$loginemail' and pass='$loginpass' LIMIT 1 "; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 
       $_SESSION=array();

       $_SESSION['fname']=$row['fname'];
       $_SESSION['lname']=$row['lname'];
       $_SESSION['status']=true;
       header('location: ../index.php');
    }
    else
    {
      echo " something wrong ";

    }
```

**NOTE:** `mysql_*` is deprecated now. user `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 1):

**Note : mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO**

Use [mysql_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to check if data is present or not in table

Try this :

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE email='".$loginemail."' and pass='".$loginpas."' ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $ispresent = mysql_num_rows($result);     



    if($ispresent > 0)
    { 
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die(mysql_error());

        $_SESSION['fname']=$row['fname'];
        $_SESSION['lname']=$row['lname'];
        $_SESSION['status']=true;
        header('location: ../index.php');
    }    
    else
    {
         echo " something wrong ";
         exit;

    }
```

**Edit :**

Also you have written wrong :

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) // Login Validation check code ** START **

    $errr = ''; // This variable will be used to indicate error of login email or pwd

    {
```

This should be :

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) // Login Validation check code ** START **
{

   $errr = '';
```

Comment: I tried it but still not working if ID pwd is correct it redirect to home page but if id pwd is not correct only blank page shows instead of " something wrong " ;

Comment: @ShaikhNomanNasir check else condition is executed or not when pwd is wrong. You can check by echoing something and then exit. see my edit

Comment: Yes I checked else condition is not executing on wrong password it shows blank page instead of showing echo

Comment: var_dump result and ispresent pls

Comment: yup @ShaikhNomanNasir try to echo the value of $ispresent as Royal Bg said

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

  { //login sucessfull

     }
 else
 {
 // incorrect 
     }
```

and change query to this

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE email='".$loginemail."' and pass='".$loginpass."';
```

and check for ' in input user name and password , you are using insecure input from user , it might cause sql injection

Comment: @SatishSharma if we found something like that will flag it , but tell other to mark , it is personal decision